# How to use set<ID> in where clause for text field - no results found

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I am Using a simple Soql Query Like below:

```
Set<Id> Testset = new Set<Id>(); 
List <BR_Channel__c> channel = [select id, BR_District__c from BR_Channel__c 
                                  where BR_District__c in : Testset];
```

Now Here `BR_District__c`  is a text field..

i have various id's stored in Testset but upon Query its not resulting to any Records.

Can we Use set of List directly with text field in where clause of Sooql?

Please Suggest, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you change Set<Id> to Set<String> ?

Comment: Why not make BR_District__c an Id field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `BR_District__c` is text field then use `set<String>` instead `Set<Id>`

```
Set<String> Testset = new Set<String>();
Testset.add('Test1');
Testset.add('Test2');

 List <BR_Channel__c> channel = [select id, BR_District__c from BR_Channel__c 
                                  where BR_District__c in : Testset];

 system.debug('==============channel ===='+channel );
```

Comment: HI All,Thanks for your promt replies..i have Tried with Using Set of String as Well But Still Sooql query is not returning anything here..

Comment: @PrateekJain issue solved?

Comment: Hi Ratan..Sry for Late Reply..Yeah it was my bad that Set of String has worked,thakns for your help..